# Numpy linspace not evenly spaced

Tags: python, numpy

I want to generate evenly spaced 50 numbers between 0 to 1

First, I tried with numpy.arange(0,1,0.02), below is the output I got.

```
[0.   0.02 0.04 0.06 0.08 0.1  0.12 0.14 0.16 0.18 0.2  0.22 0.24 0.26
 0.28 0.3  0.32 0.34 0.36 0.38 0.4  0.42 0.44 0.46 0.48 0.5  0.52 0.54
 0.56 0.58 0.6  0.62 0.64 0.66 0.68 0.7  0.72 0.74 0.76 0.78 0.8  0.82
 0.84 0.86 0.88 0.9  0.92 0.94 0.96 0.98]
```

But later I saw that the endpoint isn't part of this, so I thought of using linspace
time = np.linspace(0,1,50) and the output is

```
[0.         0.02040816 0.04081633 0.06122449 0.08163265 0.10204082
 0.12244898 0.14285714 0.16326531 0.18367347 0.20408163 0.2244898
 0.24489796 0.26530612 0.28571429 0.30612245 0.32653061 0.34693878
 0.36734694 0.3877551  0.40816327 0.42857143 0.44897959 0.46938776
 0.48979592 0.51020408 0.53061224 0.55102041 0.57142857 0.59183673
 0.6122449  0.63265306 0.65306122 0.67346939 0.69387755 0.71428571
 0.73469388 0.75510204 0.7755102  0.79591837 0.81632653 0.83673469
 0.85714286 0.87755102 0.89795918 0.91836735 0.93877551 0.95918367
 0.97959184 1.        ]
```

I didn't understand why isn't this evenly spaced because 0.02040816+0.02040816=0.04081632 but in the sequence, it shows 0.04081633, someone please explain.
To get the output like arrange I have used np.around

Comment: `np.linspace(0, 1, 51)`!? [Some more explanations on `np.linspace`](https://www.sharpsightlabs.com/blog/numpy-linspace/)

Comment: If you check using `np.diff(np.linspace(0, 1, 50))` you will see that it is evenly spaced

Comment: Thanks a lot  HansHirse and Nils Werner, so in linspace the number points should the number points+1 to include the end point!

Comment: Try something smaller where you can count the values, eg `linspace(0,1,11)` (or 10)

Answer (score 5):

As HansHirse mentioned, it should be `np.linspace(0,1,51)`, because `np.linspace` does not include the last number.

If you want to achieve the same result using `np.arange`, then simply use `np.arange(0,1.02,0.02)`. Just add the last number to the 2nd number in `np.arange` so that the last number that you expect to be printed would also get printed.

Hope that this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To achive evenly spaced 50 numbers between 0 to 1 `np.linspace(0,1,50)` is totally right!

If yo want the same result as `np.arange(0,1,0.02)` you can use `np.linspace(0,0.98,50)`, because the arange function also stopps at 0.98.

```
numpy.linspace(0,0.98,50)

array([0.  , 0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.08, 0.1 , 0.12, 0.14, 0.16, 0.18, 0.2 ,
       0.22, 0.24, 0.26, 0.28, 0.3 , 0.32, 0.34, 0.36, 0.38, 0.4 , 0.42,
       0.44, 0.46, 0.48, 0.5 , 0.52, 0.54, 0.56, 0.58, 0.6 , 0.62, 0.64,
       0.66, 0.68, 0.7 , 0.72, 0.74, 0.76, 0.78, 0.8 , 0.82, 0.84, 0.86,
       0.88, 0.9 , 0.92, 0.94, 0.96, 0.98])
```

Comment: But i wanted the endpoint 1 to be included, hence i replaced arange with linspace